# SVG: fill pattern with overlapping shapes

Tags: svg

In SVG, how can I fill portions of overlapping shapes, like this [example](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/sxhg1)(not drawn with SVG)? If I omit the fill pattern from a shape, I also want the pattern removed from other shapes that it overlaps. After that, yet more shapes may overlap again and re-draw the pattern. I'm generating this SVG from code, and for each shape, I'll know in the code whether it's supposed to add or subtract the fill pattern.

Here's my SVG so far. It draws the shapes, and defines the fill pattern but doesn't use it.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="640" height="480" viewBox="0 0 640 480">
<defs>
   <marker id="endArrowGreen" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="1" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" orient="auto" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="4">
   <polyline points="0,0 10,5 0,10 1,5" fill="#00CC00" stroke="#00CC00"/>
   </marker>
   <marker id="startArrowGreen" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="1" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" orient="auto" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="4">
     <polyline points="10,0 0,5 10,10 9,5" fill="#00CC00" stroke="#00CC00"/>
   </marker>
   <marker id="endArrowBlue" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="1" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" orient="auto" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="4">
   <polyline points="0,0 10,5 0,10 1,5" fill="#0000CC" stroke="#0000CC"/>
   </marker>
   <marker id="startArrowBlue" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="1" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" orient="auto" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="4">
   <polyline points="10,0 0,5 10,10 9,5" fill="#0000CC" stroke="#0000CC"/>
   </marker>
     <pattern id="Crosshatch" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
              x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"
              viewBox="0 0 10 10" >
       <path d="M 0 10 L 10 0" stroke-width="1" stroke="blue" />
     </pattern>
   </defs>
<g>
<line x1="7.78888" y1="6.08366" x2="319.087" y2="6.08366" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<polyline points="0,0 -6,-3 -5,0 -6,3" fill="#0000CC" stroke="#0000CC" transform="translate(319.087 6.08366) rotate(0)"/>
<line x1="319.087" y1="6.08366" x2="630.385" y2="6.08366" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<line x1="630.385" y1="6.08366" x2="630.385" y2="469.354" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<line x1="630.385" y1="469.354" x2="7.78888" y2="469.354" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<line x1="7.78888" y1="469.354" x2="7.78888" y2="237.719" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<line x1="7.78888" y1="6.08366" x2="7.78888" y2="237.719" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<polyline points="0,0 -6,-3 -5,0 -6,3" fill="#0000CC" stroke="#0000CC" transform="translate(7.78888 237.719) rotate(90)"/>
</g>
<circle cx="298.914" cy="237.087" r="218.732" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC" fill="none"/>
<circle cx="262.395" cy="238.913" r="100" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC" fill="none"/>
<circle cx="438.601" cy="236.175" r="129.523" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC" fill="none"/>
<g>
<line x1="99.913" y1="248.646" x2="302.566" y2="248.646" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<polyline points="0,0 -6,-3 -5,0 -6,3" fill="#0000CC" stroke="#0000CC" transform="translate(302.566 248.646) rotate(0)"/>
<line x1="302.566" y1="248.646" x2="505.22" y2="248.646" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<line x1="505.22" y1="248.646" x2="505.22" y2="291.232" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<line x1="505.22" y1="291.232" x2="99.913" y2="291.232" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<line x1="99.913" y1="291.232" x2="99.913" y2="269.939" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<line x1="99.913" y1="248.646" x2="99.913" y2="269.939" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<polyline points="0,0 -6,-3 -5,0 -6,3" fill="#0000CC" stroke="#0000CC" transform="translate(99.913 269.939) rotate(90)"/>
</g>
<g>
<line x1="114.521" y1="181.118" x2="303.023" y2="181.118" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<polyline points="0,0 -6,-3 -5,0 -6,3" fill="#0000CC" stroke="#0000CC" transform="translate(303.023 181.118) rotate(0)"/>
<line x1="303.023" y1="181.118" x2="491.525" y2="181.118" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<line x1="491.525" y1="181.118" x2="491.525" y2="212.753" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<line x1="491.525" y1="212.753" x2="114.521" y2="212.753" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<line x1="114.521" y1="212.753" x2="114.521" y2="196.935" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<line x1="114.521" y1="181.118" x2="114.521" y2="196.935" stroke-width="1" stroke="#0000CC"  />
<polyline points="0,0 -6,-3 -5,0 -6,3" fill="#0000CC" stroke="#0000CC" transform="translate(114.521 196.935) rotate(90)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the "fill-rule" attribute see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html